# SQL code for CUrrent Month Last Year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, dateadd

I am using the dataadd function trying to find the sum where a certain date field is in the current month but of the previous year.

```
sum(case when (mt04 >= DATEADD(MONTH,-12,getdate()) and (mt04 <= dateadd(month,-11,getdate())))
         then 1 else 0
    end) as [New Instructions Same Month Last Year],
```

This is the report I am using and at the moment it is showing the data from this point onwards to the end of the month.  E.g. if I ran it on the 8th of the month it is showing data from 8th onwards of the current month of the previous year.  I need a total for the whole month of the previous year.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is in a `sum()`, there is no advantage to putting all the function calls on the current date.  So, just use `month()` and `year()`:

```
sum(case when year(mt04) = year(getdate()) - 1 and month(mt04) = month(getdate())
         then 1 else 0
    end) as [New Instructions Same Month Last Year]
```

Comment: *"Because this is in a sum(), there is no advantage to putting all the function calls on the current date."* - This is not true, I see what you are implying with regards to it not effecting the sargability of the query, however, you are still performing functions on the date column for every row, rather than once during compilation to get a constant date. In some quick tests I have done I found using the functions on the date, rather than on `GETDATE()` is about 25% more expensive.

Comment: @GarethD . . . That's quite a difference.  I would have expected the time to load the data from disk to swamp the calling of two functions by at least an order of magnitude, if not more.

Comment: The table I ran the test on had about 25m records in, and the sum consistently took about 2 seconds (on a warm cache) using `SUM(CASE WHEN DateColumn >= '20150701' AND DateColumn < '20150801' THEN 1 ELSE 0)` compared to 2 and half seconds using `DATEPART(YEAR, DateColumn) = 2015 AND DATEPART(MONTH, DateColumn) = 7` - I appreciate that running the sum over 25m records may not be a standard scenario and on a smaller dataset the difference will probably be negligible.